# Apple Affiliate Program

Tags: itunes, affiliate

How do Apple pay for affiliate program members? Whether the money is credited to iTunes Connect? I have an app that takes the user to iTunes when they tap on the app icon. The affiliate partner is Linkshare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't pay you, Linkshare does, make sure you fill your payement method there.

Also, if you're linking to apps make sure you're subscribed to the european affiliate program as well if you'd like to maximize your affiliate profit, otherwise you'll just get a share with your US traffic. You can use [Afflr](http://www.afflr.com) to dispatch your traffic to the proper affiliate network.

Answer (score 3):

The iTunes, App Store, Mac App Store, iBookstore is managed by third-party companies.  Your payment for the program is not managed through a direct relationship with Apple.

Find out more about the program and how to get started here:
http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-app-store-affiliate-program.html

Answer (score 1):

Apple generates earnings reports and through third parties (usually banks) invoices are generated and credited to developers. First, you need to make over US$150 before they pay you. That is the "minimum payment threshold".

If you do not make over 150, it is rolled over to the next month until you pass the threshold.

Here in Brazil, the payments are made by a bank (banco Paulista) who converts the dollar in the current coin and transfers the value to your choosed bank account.

Answer (score 1):

As of late 2013 and early 2014, Apple transitioned away from it's previous relationships with LinkShare & TradeDoubler, and is currently using Performance Horizon Group for third-party affiliate management.

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/important-affiliate-program-changes.html

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/phg_transition.html

From the trend of announcements [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/archives.html) it appears that most countries are migrated (or migrating) to the PHG platform.

Whereas the previous relationships were part of much larger Affiliate Networks, PHG/iTunes appears to be a stand-alone private affiliate program, completely dedicated to Apple/iTunes.